# Best way to drop big collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have standalone MongoDB instance version 3.2. Storage engine is `WiredTiger`. What is the best way to drop big collection (>500Gb) to **minimize time of exclusive database lock**? Will be there time difference between 2 solution?

- Remove all documents from collection, drop index, drop collection
- Just drop collection

Additional information, probably it could be important:

- Collection contains about 200.000.000 documents
- Collection has only one index by `_id`
- '_id' looks like `{_id : {day: "2018-01-01", key :"someuniquekeybyday"}}`

Comment: Dropping a collection is instantaneous. At least it used to be.

Comment: It's very easy to check, btw.

Comment: I had to drop some small collections about 5-10Gb, it took several seconds. I'm afraid that dropping x100 size collection will take 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Last time I tried this, it was mmapv1. Must be WT does more work (now that collections do not directly map to files on disk). In either case, I'd bet that manually emptying the collection will take order of magnitude longer.

Comment: What you could do is delete documents in small batches. In absolute time, this will take much longer, but lock time will be spread thin. (no multi-second intervals of exclusive lock, when nobody can do anything)

Comment: Will definitely not answer your question rigorously, but I would believe such an issue in production to be more a question of growing tall vs. growing wide.
I can't see myself maintaining a 500GB database without any kind of replicas, sharding and distribution. Sharding data across multiple machines would allow you some bulk updates while still offering high availability. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/

Comment: what does replication or sharding have to do with this question @AlexisFacques

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is probably: "drop operation is not linear". It takes few seconds on 10Gb collection and it takes absolutely the same time with 500Gb collection.

I've deleted 1TB collection many times, it took several seconds.

p.s. To offer you something new, not seen in comments: you have the third option - to make a copy of **other** collections in this database and then switch database in your application.

Comment: Well, it was decided to drop collection as is. It took almost 4 minutes (~300Gb).

Comment: Maybe this option matters so much: directoryPerDB: true I have it on at every instance. And you probably do not. Unfortunately, I've recalled it only now.

Comment: Might it really matter?

Comment: I'm just guessing. Maybe he is not using XFS filesystem, ext* is slower with large files. Maybe some other problems exist. Technically collection is a single file, deleting it MUST be a matter of 3-5 seconds.

Comment: By this solution, In huge database, it need too many disk size, to copy database. So, in some cases it is not possible!!

Answer (score 0):

I have dropped over 1.4 TB collection on version 4.0. Operation took less than 1 sec.

> 2022-03-15T01:17:25.688+0000 I REPL     [replication-2] Completing collection drop for order.system.drop.1647307045i163t6.feeds with drop optime { ts: Timestamp(1647307045, 163), t: 6 } (notification optime: { ts: Timestamp(1647307045, 163), t: 6 })

As per documentation drop operation will obtain lock on affected database & will block all the operations, so application will suffer minor latencies in database operations for short duration. before dropping large collection make sure...

- remove all read/writes from application on that collection
- rename to temporary collection to avoid any operation during drop.
- choose least traffic time to drop temporary collection.